# Output not connecting as input in ArcGIS ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, modelbuilder, clip

[image]

As seen in the image, I am trying to connect "Output Dataset" i.a result of merge of 2 shapefiles as input in the CLIP tool.

As you can see in the image(in the red highlighted area), input option is not coming when I am trying to connect "Output Dataset" with CLIP.

What should I do?

Comment: Did you try removing Clip and re-adding? Or save the model and exit, and then reopen.

Answer (score 3):

You probably have the inputs incorrectly set in the tool. You appear to have lines and polys based on the names.

You can clip lines by using a polygon. You can’t clip polygons by using lines. Try changing the parameter input your have roads hooked into.